# Data.table - For efficiently summing over previous rows under a set of conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Say I have a dataframe

```
  block trial subject feedback stim1 stim2     stim_time
1    13     0    1003        1     2     3 1607325455244
2    13     1    1003        1     1     3 1607325462034
3    13     3    1003        1     2     1 1607325474049
4    15     0    1003        1     3     2 1607362013026
5    15     1    1003        1     3     1 1607362019190
6    15     3    1003        1     1     2 1607362030586
7    29     2    1003        0     3     1 1607677989379
```

my objective is to
create a new columns titled "left_time_spent" and "right_time_spent".

1. I group by  subject and block
2. Calculate the stim_time difference between the current and the minimum stim_time for each number in stim 1 and stim2
   a) within that block + whatever time was spent in previous blocks .
3. if feedback (column 4) =0 i do not want to include that time in the calculation and therefore it would carry over the previous value.

Since that was a mouthful let me try and explain through a few examples

```
row 3. 
stim1=2. 
1) I look back to the very first instance (whithin this block) where either stim1==2 or stim2==2 and take that stim_time (in this case its 1607325455244)
2) subtract current stim_time from first stim_time =1607325474049  -1607325455244=18805
3) so left_spent_time[3]=18805

stim2=2. it was presented as stim1 in row 2 
so right_time_spent[3]=1607325474049-1607325462034=12015

Now in row 4, it's a new block. stim2=2. Within this block, this is the first element so I pass (1607362013026-1607362013026=0)+time spent on it in a previous block.  

so right_time_spent[4]=left_time_spent(3)=18960

in row 4, stim1=3. its a new block so we simply carry over the previous time that stim 3 was learned. 
left_time_spent[4]=0+right_time_spent(2)


finally in row  7, feedback=0 so 
left_time_spent[7]=left_time_spent[5]
right_time_spent[7]=left_time_spent[6]
```

In total my desired output should look like this

```
 block trial subject feedback stim1 stim2     stim_time left_time_spent right_time_spent
1    13     0    1003        1     2     3 1607325455244               0                0
2    13     1    1003        1     1     3 1607325462034               0             6790
3    13     3    1003        1     2     1 1607325474049           18805            12015
4    15     0    1003        1     3     2 1607362013026            6790            18805
5    15     1    1003        1     3     1 1607362019190           12954            12015
6    15     3    1003        1     1     2 1607362030586           23411            36365
7    29     2    1003        0     3     1 1607677989379           12954            23411
```

its a fairly complex procedure full of steps- an efficient way to do it would be incredible.

For each new subject the calculation is applied separately.

Thank you in advance!

dput is here

```
structure(list(block = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 29L), 
    trial = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L), subject = c(1003, 
    1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003), feedback = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), stim1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L
    ), stim2 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), stim_time = structure(c(7.94124289122202e-312, 
    7.94124292476908e-312, 7.94124298413107e-312, 7.94142351066377e-312, 
    7.94142354111797e-312, 7.9414235974217e-312, 7.94298464127292e-312
    ), class = "integer64"), left_time_spent = c(0, 0, 18805, 
    6790, 12954, 23411, 12954), right_time_spent = c(0, 6790, 
    12015, 18805, 12015, 36365, 23411)), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I feel your past 3 posts are the same question, could you link them up, and explain why this post is different?

Comment: they are from the same dataset but require completely different manipulations (as far as I understand- being a novice)

Comment: You group by subject and block, but don't describe what happens when the subject changes.

Comment: This is not an Rcpp question so I will remove the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: the above calculation is applied to each subject separately- i edited the post to hopefully make that clear as well

Comment: Your descriptions seem inconsistent and are a bit confusing. For instance, you say *"Now in row 4, it's a new block. stim2=1"* but neither `stim#` value is 1. It also seems that either `stim1` -> `left_time_spent` (and 2 -> right) or there is some other way to infer what goes in which.

Comment: It also seems that either stim1 -> left_time_spent (and 2 -> right)  is exactly correct!
and you were absolutely right - that one entry was a typo on my part- everything else is in order. if there is something else unclear, please let me know!